# Joi validation for array of dynamic objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, validation, joi

I am trying to validate array of objects where objects may increase if user clicks on a button and user has an ability to delete the objects.I tried with joi api

Example:

```
    Services[
                {
                    service1:'number',
                    service2:'number',
                    service3:'number'
                },
                {
                    service1:'number',
                        service2:'number',
                    service3:'number'
                },
                {
                    service1:'number',
                        service2:'number',
                    service3:'number'
                }
         ];
     const schema = Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
         service1:Joi.string().regex(/^/).required().label(" ").options({
            language: {
                any: {
                    empty: 'Please enter number.',
                    required: 'Please enter a valid number.'
                },
                string: {
                    regex: {
                        base: 'Please enter a valid number.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
        service2:Joi.string().regex(/^/).required().label(" ").options({
            language: {
                any: {
                    empty: 'Please enter number.',
                    required: 'Please enter a valid number.'
                },
                string: {
                    regex: {
                        base: 'Please enter a valid number.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
        service3:Joi.string().regex(/^/).required().label(" ").options({
            language: {
                any: {
                    empty: 'Please enter number.',
                    required: 'Please enter a valid number.'
                },
                string: {
                    regex: {
                        base: 'Please enter a valid number.'
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }));
```

and then Joi.validate(values, schema);
Joi is not able pickup the object keys,so it not throwing any errors even user enters incorrect input.

Comment: What is not working? What is the output you're getting and what is the output you expect?

Comment: I am getting an error as Invalid schema object.

Comment: @Sree can you please edit your question to include the full error that you're getting. Joi will often tell you about where your object is failing validation.